# auth:web fails to auhenticate where auth:api works, with the same code

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-6

I need to authenticate my web routes and I decided to use this middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::get('test', 'MainController@home');
    Route::get('test1', 'MainController@home1');
});
```

I edited `config/auth.php` file to use my guard:

```
....
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'oauth2',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'oauth2',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
...
```

I defined oauth2 in the `AuthServiceProvider` file like this:

```
Auth::extend('oauth2', function ($app, $name, array $config) {
    // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard ...
    return new OAuth2Guard(app(TokenUserProvider::class), $app->make('request'));
});
```

This code works well. The `auth:api` middleware is executed and the user is checked.

Now since I need the sessions I wanted to use `auth:web` middleware, with the same exact code. But If I use it the user is nomore authenticated and he is redirected to the login page.

I do not know why. Both `web` and `api` guards use the same driver.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provide separate file for API routes `routes/api.php` you can separate web and api routes routes. all API routes will be prefixed with "api". After separating routes just include 'web' middle-ware

Comment: Sorry but you did not answer to my question

Comment: wht you can't use "session" driver for web  ??

Comment: because I need to authenticate the use from header token

Comment: I have use jwt for authentications along with sessions like, for web "'driver' => 'session'," and for api "'driver' => 'jwt',"

Comment: you can use laravel passport for token.